# CNContactViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty = false not respected

Tags: ios9, cncontactviewcontroller

Despite returning `false` from `contactViewController:shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty:`, iOS 9 seems to override this setting and performs the default action.

For example, tapping on a contact's address property in a `CNContactViewController` redirects to the Apple Maps app.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

Present a `CNContactViewController` for a `CNContact`, via the following Swift code:

```
func showContactViewController(forContact contact: CNContact) {
    let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forContact: contact)
    contactViewController.contactStore = contactStore
    contactViewController.delegate = self
    contactViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(contactViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Programmatically return `false` from the `CNContactViewControllerDelegate` method:

```
// Implement this method to determine the resulting behavior when a property is selected.
// Return false if you do not want anything to be done or if you are handling the actions yourself.
func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

In the presented `CNContactViewController`, tap on the contact's address property.

User will be redirected to Apple Maps app, despite returning `false` from the aforementioned delegate method.

Any ideas as to how to prevent this redirect?

Comment: Same problem when user taps phone number: a normal call is activated. Once call is cancelled, execution then only seems to enter this delegate function, judging from breakpoint. Adding `contactDetailViewController.allowsActions = false` causes action buttons not to be displayed, but that is all. Seems CNContactViewController is still a bit broken?